# DjangoCMS Sekizai {% render_block "js" %} disable usage of jQuery

Tags: jquery, django, django-cms, django-templates, django-sekizai

I'm working on DjangoCMS app, which includes its custom javascript file, but I have a problem with using jQuery after using templatetag render_block.

After creating a new project here is my project structure:

```
project/
    apps/
        myapp/
    static/
        js/
            custom.js
    templates/
        base.html
        header.html
        menu.html
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
```

**base.html**

```
{% load cms_tags menu_tags sekizai_tags staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}This is my new project home page{% endblock title %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        {% include "header.html" %}
        {% show_menu 0 100 100 100 "menu.html" %}
     </div>
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
    {% render_block "js" %}
    {% addtoblock 'js' %}
         <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static "js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
         <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static "js/custom.js" %}"></script>
    {% endaddtoblock 'js' %}
</body>
</html>
```

**project/apps/myapp/templates/myapp/home.html**

```
{% extends CMS_TEMPLATE %}
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags staticfiles %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

There is no content in *home.html*, yet. But the content from base.html renders properly.
The problem is in *custom.js* which uses jQuery.

**custom.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Hi");
});
```

Alert message never pop up, and I get message *"undefined is not a function"*. **The main problem that bothers me is that jQuery is included in my source code**, but I can't use it.

**source code**

```
<html>
...
<body>
    ....
    <script>
    var _jQuery = window.jQuery || undefined;
    var _$ = window.$ || undefined;
    </script>
    <script src="/static/cms/js/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/cms/js/libs/class.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/cms/js/modules/jquery.ui.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/cms/js/modules/jquery.ui.nestedsortable.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/cms/js/modules/cms.base.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/cms/js/modules/cms.modal.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/cms/js/modules/cms.sideframe.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/cms/js/modules/cms.clipboard.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/cms/js/modules/cms.plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/cms/js/modules/cms.structureboard.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/cms/js/modules/cms.toolbar.js"></script>
    ...
    <script type='text/javascript' src="/static/js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously {% render_block "js" %} works fine, but I found that because of it, CMS.$ will be passed for $. Because of that I added:

```
<script> $ = CMS.$ </script>
```

on the top of my `addtoblock`:

```
{% addtoblock 'js' %}
    <script>$=CMS.$</script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static "js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static "js/custom.js" %}"></script>
{% endaddtoblock 'js' %}
```

My problem with alert was resolved, but Bootstrap still reports that ther is no jQuery:

> Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Adding jQuery in `addtoblock` can resolve the problem, but then there will be two same jQuery files in my source code and that is unnecessary.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick glance at the bootstrap source tells me they check for `jQuery`, not `$`. Try changing your `<script>$ = CMS.$</script>` to `<script>jQuery = CMS.$</script>`.

However, be aware that the CMS jQuery will only be loaded if the toolbar is active, as in, only for logged-in staff users.

Comment: Thank you for your note, actually that resolved my problem with two jQuery files.